# print numpy array of utf-8?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have the following python2.7 code, which predict the testing values (Arabic words), but the results are given in number not in string as follows :

```
['\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x85\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84'
 '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x85\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84']
```

my python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier


class MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        # this line is different from python2 version - no more itervalues
        self.dim = len(list(word2vec.values())[0])

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return np.array([
            np.mean([self.word2vec[w] for w in words if w in self.word2vec]
                    or [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
            for words in X
        ])

w2v = {
    'من': [1, 1],
    'العراق': [1.01, 1.01],
    'مصر': [1.02, 1.02],
    'مال':    [-1, -1],
    'حرف جر':    [-1.01, -1.01],
    'السودان':    [-1.02, -1.02],
    'فلوس':   [1, -1],
    'دولة': [1.01, -1.01],
    'مصاري':    [1.02, -1.02]
}

model = Pipeline([
    ("word2vec vectorizer", MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(w2v)),
    ("extra trees", ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=200))])

X = [['في'],
     ['عقود']]
y = ['حرف جر', 'المال']
model.fit(X, y)
# never before seen words!!!
test_X = [['من'], ['فلوس']]
print(model.predict(test_X))
```

so how i can print the Arabic words !

i tried to check the results array suing :

```
arr = model.predict(test_X)

print(np.info(arr))
```

and got the following results:

```
class:  ndarray
shape:  (2,)
strides:  (11,)
itemsize:  11
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  True
data pointer: 0x1189760
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: |S11
None
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
arr = model.predict(test_X)
for e in arr:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
المال
المال
```